# Access form combobox default value vs options

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have an Access table "Contacts" that looks like this:

```
Contact          Extension
Bill Mann        7283
Jim Bob          2563
Sue Zan          5963
etc...
```

I have another table "Departments" that looks like this:

```
Department       Description
0040             Fun station
0110             Happy town
0110C            Happy town with clowns
etc...
```

I have created a form that pulls in data from Contacts as well as Departments to make some assignments:

[image]

What I would like to do is automatically populate this form upon opening, with the latest assignments that were made by the form. Then these assignments can be changed and saved at will. To me this seems to mean that the combobox will be assigned a default value from a table that is distinct from the Contacts and Departments tables. The problem I am running into is that I can't seem to find a way to assign those default values and allow all of the possible choices from Contacts and Departments.

I am happy to use a VBA solution if necessary.

Comment: You have no relationship between 'Contacts' and 'Departments' (and without column headers, I'm clueless as to what those combo boxes are for). Once you relate the tables (meaning you either need a 3rd table or you need to add a field to one of the others. The combo boxes on your form will be able to display the list you want AND your new table will save the unique value for you.

Comment: What happens when you click your Save Changes button? I'm assuming the department assignments get stored somewhere and the form gets reset or closed. It would help to know what the table where the output is stored looks like. I think the answer is going to be that combo boxes have a Default Value property that can use a function where you can look up the previously assigned value, but I would need more information to be more specific than that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need a third table to save the "Packaging Materials Assignments" and that the form should be bound to that table.

Then you set each of the fields on the form from each of the comboBoxes. Then save the record and your current assignments are saved.

When you open the form, you see the way the assignments were most recently set. Then you can change the assignments if needed.

I might be convenient if you set the form's Property.Cycle = "Current Record". That way there will only ever be one record in the third table. Also after creating your one record, set "Allow Additions" and "Allow Deletions" to be false for the form.